# How to upload file at same time as other data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a file upload in a form but I cannot save it at the same time as other elements either in same model or two separate models. I understand my first issue was that I could NOT have nested forms e.g.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <form class="form-horizontal">
       <input />
       <input />
           @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
           {
              <form class="form-horizontal">
              <input image upload/>
              <input />

             </form>
           }
    </form>
}
```

So I now have two separate forms and can work well but I want a few things:
1. When a user selects the image to upload any currently entered values not to be deleted 2. Update the models with all the inputted data (all form elements ) along with the image to the selected models. 3. Is there any way to do this in one form at all? (in a one-r!).

How will I achieve this? My current workings is below.

View:

```
 @model client.Models.jobs

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Job Details";
}

<br /><br /><br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Job Details</legend>

            <!--Postcode search--><label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Job's Name</label>
            <input name="jobname" type="text" placeholder="Job Name" /><br /><br />


            <label for="jobdescription" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Job Description</label>
            <br /><br />
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="textArea" placeholder="Write here..."></textarea>
                <span class="help-block">The more details you enter the easier the Tradesmen can work</span>
            </div>

            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <label for="uploadphotos" class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                Add PHOTOS (Optional)

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageData, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <input name="Image" type="file" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageData)

                <button type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Home")'">Upload</button>
                @ViewBag.Message

            </label>


            <br /><br />
            <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tell us which stage you’re at</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <select class="form-control" name="stage">
                    <option>Preplan</option>
                    <option>already started</option>
                    <option>Almost finished</option>
                    <option>Needs redone fully</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br /><br /><br /><br />

            <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> When would you like the job to start?*</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <select class="form-control" name="startjob">
                    <option>ASAP</option>
                    <option>1-2 weeks</option>
                    <option>1 month</option>
                    <option>1+</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">What's your approximate budget?</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <select class="form-control" name="budget">
                    <option>£0-500</option>
                    <option>£500-100</option>
                    <option>£1000-2000</option>
                    <option>£2000+</option>
                </select>
            </div>


            <br /><br /><br /><br />





    </form>
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("getJobFormValues", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <input name="jobname" type="text" placeholder="Job Name" /><br /><br />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Next</button>

     </form>

}

@section Scripts{
   <script>
      debugger
   </script>
}
```

Controller and Actions:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create(uploadedfiles pic, HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (image != null)
                {
                    //attach the uploaded image to the object before saving to Database
                    pic.ContentType = Convert.ToString(image.ContentLength);
                    pic.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                    image.InputStream.Read(pic.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);

                    //Save image to file
                    var filename = image.FileName;
                    var filePathOriginal = Server.MapPath("/Content/Uploads/Originals");
                    var filePathThumbnail = Server.MapPath("/Content/Uploads/Thumbs");
                    string savedFileName = Path.Combine(filePathOriginal, filename);
                    image.SaveAs(savedFileName);

                    //Read image back from file and create thumbnail from it
                    var imageFile = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Originals"), filename);
                    using (var srcImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile))
                    using (var newImage = new Bitmap(100, 100))
                    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        graphics.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
                        newImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                        var thumbNew = File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
                        pic.ImageData = thumbNew.FileContents;
                        pic.ImageName = filename;
                    }
                }

                //Save model object to database
                db.uploadedfiles.Add(pic);

                ViewBag.Message = "Image Uploaded Successfully!!";

                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                    throw;
                }

                ViewBag.Message = "Image Uploaded Successfully!!";

                return View("JobDetails");
               //return RedirectToAction("getJobFormValues");

            }

            return View("JobDetails");
        }

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult getJobFormValues(jobs job)
        {
            string quoteSearch = Request["quoteSearch"];
            string jobname = Request["jobname"];
            string jobmessage = Request["textArea"];
            string uploadedphoto = Request["uploadphotos"];
            string stage = Request["stage"];
            string startjob = Request["startjob"];
            string budget = Request["budget"];
            int imgid = 2;



            //Save model object to database
            //Save personal details model object to database
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                //Save model object to database
                db.jobs.Add(new jobs
                {
                    name = jobname,
                    jobmessage = jobmessage,
                    //iscomplete
                    //jobbyuserid
                    //responsibletradesmanid
                    //jobmessage
                    stage = stage,
                    startjob = startjob,
                    budget = Convert.ToInt32(budget),
                    ImageId = imgid
                    //ImageName
                    //ImageAlt
                    //ImageData
                    //ContentType
                });

                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                    throw;
                }




            return RedirectToAction("PersonalDetails", new
                {
                    quoteSearch = quoteSearch,
                    jobname = jobname,
                    jobmessage = jobmessage,
                    uploadedphoto = uploadedphoto,
                    stage = stage,
                    startjob = startjob,
                    budget = budget
                });
            }//model state

            return View("JobDetails");

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I hope this will help anyone in same situation(i.e. learners!). After hunting around I realised that if (I could be wrong!) working with complex objects such as images text will just be strung along anyway with the .Add and .Save as long as they're part of the Model like so:
namespace client.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class jobs
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> iscomplete { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> jobbyuserid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> responsibletradesmanid { get; set; }
        public string jobmessage { get; set; }
        public string stage { get; set; }
        public string startjob { get; set; }
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public string ImageAlt { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public string Budget { get; set; }
    }
    }

Then chop up the Action to create,hold,save,image data etc but MOST IMPORTANTLY you do not need to define any fields from the form 
   `(string quoteSearch = Request["quoteSearch"]; etc.)` as they will be updated with the model. So the only difference here is that I have removed the form requests and removed saving single items like  

      //Save model object to database
                    db.jobs.Add(new jobs
                    {
                        name = jobname,

and then only used one action for both image and form data all put together nicely like so:




     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
     public ActionResult Create(jobs pic, HttpPostedFileBase image)
     {
     var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    var contextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(context);
    ////Pull out the current username from cookie into var
    //usernameCookie = new HttpCookie("CurrentUsername");
    //usernameCookie = contextBase.User.Request.Cookies["CurrentUsername"];

        //Get email from OWIN
        string usernameCookie = contextBase.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                //attach the uploaded image to the object before saving to 


        Database
                    pic.ContentType = Convert.ToString(image.ContentLength);
                    pic.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                    image.InputStream.Read(pic.ImageData, 0, 
       image.ContentLength);

                    //Save image to file
                    var filename = image.FileName;
                    var filePathOriginal = 
       Server.MapPath("/Content/Uploads/Originals");
                    var filePathThumbnail = 
       Server.MapPath("/Content/Uploads/Thumbs");
                    string savedFileName = Path.Combine(filePathOriginal, 
       filename);
                    image.SaveAs(savedFileName);

                    //Read image back from file and create thumbnail from it
                    var imageFile = 
        Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Originals"), filename);
                    using (var srcImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile))
                    using (var newImage = new Bitmap(100, 100))
                    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                        graphics.InterpolationMode = 
        InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        graphics.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 
         100));
                        newImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                        var thumbNew = File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
                        pic.ImageData = thumbNew.FileContents;
                        pic.ImageName = filename;
                    }
                }

                //Save model object to database
                db.jobs.Add(pic);

                ViewBag.Message = "Image Uploaded Successfully!!";

                int newJobID = 0;

                try
            {
                //this saves model with image
                db.SaveChanges();

                //get last inserted row ID
                newJobID = pic.id;

                //get row based on last inserted for updating the imageID as we want them correlate
                // make sure you have the right column/variable used here
                var rowToUpdate = db.jobs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == newJobID);
                if (rowToUpdate == null) throw new Exception("Invalid id: " + newJobID);
                // this variable is tracked by the db context
                rowToUpdate.ImageId = newJobID;

                var addLoggedInUserToTable = db.tradesusers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.email == usernameCookie);
                if (addLoggedInUserToTable == null) throw new Exception("Invalid id: " + usernameCookie);
                addLoggedInUserToTable.lastpostedjobid = newJobID;

                if (addLoggedInUserToTable.email == usernameCookie) { 
                rowToUpdate.jobbyuserid = addLoggedInUserToTable.id;
            }

                //reasave Model with updated ID
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }

            ViewBag.Message = "Image Uploaded Successfully!!";

            //return View("JobDetails");
            return RedirectToAction("PersonalDetails", new { usernameCookie = usernameCookie });

        }

        return View("JobDetails");
    }`enter code here`

I believe retrieving the images is a bit more straight forward! ;-)
```